# How to make a Portal component in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

A portal would be a component that render it's child components in another place of the dom tree.

e.g.

How can I make a component that isn't inside the `body` but will render it's child components inside of the `body` element?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking a Portal is use to render content outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component and also useful to render dynamic content. Portals need a reference element/component to attach to it. For example in angular CDK you have Portal and PortalOutlet(reference element).

Blazor does not offer this functionality natively, but you can do something similar using 
RenderFragment and a service.

Suppose you have a component, your PortalOutlet. This component has a parameter of the RenderFragment type, it also exposes a service to attach and detach content to this Renderfragment. You could use this service to inject components / content from another component and get an effect similar to portals. See an example of this service here

https://github.com/amuste/DnetOverlay/blob/master/src/DnetOverlayComponent/Infrastructure/Services/OverlayService.cs.

You can see a complete implementation here
https://github.com/amuste/DnetOverlay

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the entire main layout in a component with a render fragment and pass your portal component ref as cascading value. This way child components can look for it and add stuff there, without a service